# Android - The Method i(String, String) is undefined for the type Log

Tags: java, android, listview, logging, onitemclicklistener

I keep getting this error in my Main.Activity.java.

```
    The Method i(String, String) is undefined for the type Log
```

The error happens on this line:

```
Log.i("HelloListView", "You clicked Item: " + id + " at position:" + position);
```

I do not know what is wrong, so here is my whole MainActivity.java. If someone could help, that would be great.

```
    package com.example.uc.pf;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //* *EDIT* * 
    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Log.i("HelloListView", "You clicked Item: " + id + " at position:" + position);
        // Then you start a new Activity via Intent
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this, ListItemDetail.class);
        intent.putExtra("position", position);
        // Or / And
        intent.putExtra("id", id);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the future, please copy and paste your error message rather than typing them. I edited out a subtle typo that suggested a different reason for your problem.

Comment: I did copy and paste though..? Ah I guess it doesn't matter. Thanks I suppose.

Comment: That's strange...the error message had `log` while the code you say causes the error has `Log`. If the answers given didn't completely solve your problem, then double-check the capitalization.

Comment: @Code-guru.  Actually, your edit almost hid the problem!

Comment: @Simon It's possible that there are more than one problem here since other's pointed out a completely separate issue that I missed initially. I made the edit and my initial comment because an answer about fixing the import statement was accepted.

Comment: No, I believe it was my fault because I did write the error but didn't realize it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are importing `org.apache.commons.logging.Log;`.
Change to [`android.util.Log`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)

Comment: both "position" and "id" are integers, you havt to convert it to a String using String.valueOf(id) + String.valueOf(position)

Comment: Actually, you don't. Java does that automatically in this case.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using a different logging feature than the native android one: android.util.Log. If your heart is set on using the apache one, using Log.info(java.lang.Object message, java.lang.Throwable t) should work.